# how to place many table side by side with scrollable inline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to show tables in different height (rows) inline,
with the abillity to scroll (left cause it’s rtl).

It’s something like 20 maybe 30 tables.
Thanks for the help!

Below is the html with less tables:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div style='overflow: scroll;display: block;'>  
          <table id="point" style="float: right">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td class="textFont" style="font weight:bold;height: 20px">
                  <label class="sp">point</label>
                  <label class="pm"> </label><br>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td class="textFont" style="height: 30px;">
                  <label>point</label>
                  <label>point</label>
                  <label></label>
                </td>
             </tr>                                          
            </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
```

Comment: Try with `display:inline-table` No need to use `float:right`.

Comment: tried that, it's show it as like one column.

Comment: Did you checked the demo I have shared?

Comment: yes, it still doesn't let it scroll ...

Comment: Check now, you need to use `white-space:nowrap` on the container `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:inline-table` and `float:right` is not mandatory

And you need to use `white-space:nowrap` on the container `div`.

**Demo**

```css
.point
{
   display:inline-table;
   border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div style='overflow: scroll;display: block;white-space:nowrap;'>
  <table class="point">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="sp">point</label>
          <label class="pm"> </label><br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="sp">point</label>
          <label class="pm"> </label><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>point</label>
          <label>point</label>
          <label></label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>point</label>
          <label>point</label>
          <label></label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="point">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="sp">point</label>
          <label class="pm"> </label><br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="sp">point</label>
          <label class="pm"> </label><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>point</label>
          <label>point</label>
          <label></label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>point</label>
          <label>point</label>
          <label></label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="point">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="sp">point</label>
          <label class="pm"> </label><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>point</label>
          <label>point</label>
          <label></label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="point">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label class="sp">point</label>
          <label class="pm"> </label><br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="sp">point</label>
          <label class="pm"> </label><br>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label class="sp">point</label>
          <label class="pm"> </label><br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>point</label>
          <label>point</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>point</label>
          <label>point</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>point</label>
          <label>point</label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Flex?

```html
<table id="point" style="float: right">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" style="font-weight: bold;height: 20px">
        <label class="sp">point</label>
        <label class="pm"> </label><br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" style="height: 30px;">
        <label>point</label>
        <label>point</label>
        
      </td>
      <td class="textFont" style="height: 30px;">
        <label>point</label>
        <label>point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

```css
.textFont{
font-weight: bold;
height: 20px;
}

.header{
background-color:#d4d9de;
text-align:center;
}
.wrap{
display:flex;
overflow:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
}

table{
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<table id="point1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont header" colspan="2">
        <label class="sp" >point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" >
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    
      <td class="textFont">
        <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont">
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table id="point2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont header" colspan="2">
        <label class="sp" >point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" >
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    
      <td class="textFont">
        <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont">
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table id="point3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont header" colspan="2">
        <label class="sp" >point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" >
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    
      <td class="textFont">
        <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont">
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table id="point4">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont header" colspan="2">
        <label class="sp" >point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" >
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    
      <td class="textFont">
        <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont">
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table id="point5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont header" colspan="2">
        <label class="sp" >point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" >
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    
      <td class="textFont">
        <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont">
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table id="point6">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont header" colspan="2">
        <label class="sp" >point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" >
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    
      <td class="textFont">
        <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont">
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table id="point7">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont header" colspan="2">
        <label class="sp" >point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" >
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    
      <td class="textFont">
        <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont">
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table id="point8">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont header" colspan="2">
        <label class="sp" >point</label>
        
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="textFont" >
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    
      <td class="textFont">
        <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="textFont">
         <label>point point</label>
        <p>point point</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
</div>
```